# Mysql sed error

Tags: mysql, upgrade, sed

I upgraded mysql from 5.5 to 5.6 in Debian 7 Wheezy box via `apt-get` command and all seems fine, but when I restart mysql, I get:

```
[info] Stopping MySQL Community Server 5.6.23. 
...... 
[info] MySQL Community Server 5.6.23 is stopped. 
[info] Re-starting MySQL Community Server 5.6.23. sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s' 
...... 
[info] MySQL Community Server 5.6.23 is started.
```

I have no lines in the error.log, so I don't know where to start to find what file is causing that error...

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: debian 7 "wheezy"

Comment: What method did you use to upgrade? apt-get, compiling? Please give us clear explanation because the upgrading was critical step for this problem

Comment: I used apt-get. Never compiled

Comment: Did I answer your question? If you need more information feel free to ask

Comment: I`m sorry. Looks like this is debian specific issue. I'm familiar with mysql but not with debian. Maybe some debian expert out there can help you. I'll edit your question to bumping it and adding additional info